# Magento 2.1 proxy with di preference

Tags: magento-2.1, di

I am adding another type of related products.
I am adding a new method to Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link class by way of di.xml preference. The method also does appear in the interceptor class.

However, when I follow the execution, this call is made:
`$this->_linkInstance = $productLink;`

Where $productLink is returning type Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link\Proxy

When I look in this class at run time there is no reference to my method like there is for other relations:

`public function useRelatedLinks()
    {
        return $this->_getSubject()->useRelatedLinks();
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue above by extending the proxy class itself by including the following:

In di.xml add this preference:

`<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link\Proxy"
        type="SprintIntercom\RelatedDownloads\Model\Catalog\Product\Link\Proxy"/>`

Then created a class in my custom module at Vendor\Module\Model\Catalog\Product\Link\Proxy.php

`class Proxy extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link\Proxy`

And included the method:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function useCustomLinks()
{
    return $this->_getSubject()->useCustomLinks();
}
```